# PHP compare arrays and remove NOT matched objects

Tags: php, arrays

I want to compare two arrays with each other and remove all objects from the first one who are NOT present in both arrays.

```
    //array1
    $apiData1 = [
       'test1' => ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"],
       'test2' => ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"],
       'test3' => ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"],
       'test4' => ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"],
       'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' => ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"],
    ];

    // ======================

    //array2
    $apiData2 = [
       'test1' => ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"],
       'test2' => ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"],
       'test3' => ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"],
       'test4' => ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"],
       'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB' => ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"],
    ];
```

The result should be array1 without the 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' object.

```
//array1
$apiData1 = [
   'test1' => ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"],
   'test2' => ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"],
   'test3' => ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"],
   'test4' => ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"],
];
```

What I tried:

```
foreach ($apiData2 as $key => $value) {

    if ((isset($apiData1[$key]) && !isset($apiData2[$key])) || (!isset($apiData1[$key]) && isset($apiData2[$key]))) {

        unset($apiData1[$key]);

    }

}
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Does it matter if the values of test1, test2, etc match?

Comment: @ntd added what I tried so far

Comment: @User1010 no I just wont to compare the index if it exists in both not the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) is what you're looking for. It takes two or more arrays, and returns a new array containing the elements of the **first** array, whose keys are present in all provided arrays.